# Configure credentials for AWS Elastic Container Registry for minikube using registry at ubuntu inside vm with none driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, minikube, amazon-ecr

Hello everyone I am working on ubuntu under VM in windows 10 and I want to configure credentials for AWS Elastic Container Registry for minikube and none as virtualization driver, I tried many ways like in this link https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/configuring_creds_for_aws_ecr/ but I can't pull images from private ECR repo so could anyone help me to do so ?
thank you in advance.